# Ajax call for getIndexes MongoDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mongodb

I wonder if there is some way possible to get all indexes for a mongoDB with an Ajax call or similiar?

When I was looking through the documentation I found this about getIndexes():
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/ but this seems to be a mongoDB shell function...

I would wanna get all indexes somehow like this:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: "URL FOR QUERING ALL INDEXES",
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('success', data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('error', errorThrown);
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to interact with MongoDB directly via AJAX, because MongoDB doesn't work that way.

What you need to do is write server-side code to handle the AJAX request and interact with the database, then return the response, exactly as you would if you were using a relational database. Most server-side languages have bindings for MongoDB.

If you want a database you can interact with via AJAX, then CouchDB is what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

It is posible to interact with MongoDB this way but the built in REST interface does not house the capacity to get this kind of information.

Generally speaking using REST to your database directly is a security risk.

If you wanted to go a little further and install a little something you can look at thios page about what's available: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/